# Visual Studio 2013 Express and Web Essentials extension

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sass, web-essentials

I installed VS Express for Web 2013 in both Windows 7. Then I downloaded and run WebEssentials which on one computer it works and the others it doesn't.
The one that it doesn't when I try say:
No program compatible to open Web Essentials.
And if I check the log it list just 
Visual Studio Update 4 as compatible programs.

I try to install also Web Workbench and it also do the same.

Any idea why it happening or how can I discover more of my programs and understand what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I've noticed when downloading something from Microsoft it will have _exe instead of .exe at the end.  If it did that, just change the _ to a . before the exe and it will work.